# How to redirect / to home.php? (PHPBB/BLOG)

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, homepage

I want my site address to redirect:

- `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/home.php`

I want to use this method to avoid it going to the index.php of that of my blog or phpb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this thread will quickly be downvoted, but .htaccess is your friend

Google will give you lots of options, but

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

or

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/home.php
```

should do it...

Comment: I was going to downvote you just for saying that. But this is definitely a good approach.

Comment: "thread" added to clarify :)